# Openpyxl - How to reference cell on another sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way to reference a cell A1 from Sheet2 to cell A1 of Sheet1?

> ='Sheet2'!A1

in the active worksheet?

Apparently, the following doesn't work

```
wb = load_workbook(test.xlsx)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

ws['A1'] = "='Sheet2'!A1)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you save the workbook using **wb.save**? and Also remove the **)** in the formula.

use this code below for achieving the functionality.

```
import  openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws['A1'] = "='Sheet2'!A1" 
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Yes, I saved it after. Dunno why it wasn't working... Thanks alot this works!

Comment: thats great @GiorgosSynetos